# Store timestamp to BigQuery with specific timezone

Tags: python, google-bigquery, yaml

I have a csv with timestamp in UTC8.

`whatever.csv`:

```
timestamp
2020-09-09 11:42:33
2020-09-09 11:42:51
2020-09-09 11:49:29
```

I want to store them in BQ. After storing to BQ, this is the result I'm getting :

[image]

It said UTC instead of UTC+8.

However, the timestamp is correct but is there any way I can store it like this `2020-09-11 19:58:51 UTC+8` ? or something related as long as it reflect the actual timezone of the timestamp..

Secondly, can I specify the requirement in field schema since I'm storing this using python script and mapping it through schema from a YAML file such as :

somefile.yaml:

```
  schema:
    - name: "timestamp"
      type: "TIMESTAMP"
      mode: "NULLABLE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to state more about what do you want to achieve to get better help.

For one, BigQuery always stores TIMESTAMP in UTC. I have to guess that you don't really need the timestamp to be **stored** in certain timezone (because I can't imagine why does it matter to you how the ts is stored), you care more about how to display the timestamp in UTC+8. If my guess is right, there are 2 ways:

```sql
SELECT STRING(TIMESTAMP "2008-12-25 15:30:00+00", "UTC+8")
```

The approach requires you to decorate each of your TS columns, an one thing for all approach could be

```sql
SET @@time_zone = "Asia/Shanghai";
-- All subsequent query will use time zone "Asia/Shanghai"
SELECT STRING(TIMESTAMP "2008-12-25 15:30:00+00");
```

Both ones output:

```
+------------------------+
|          f0_           |
+------------------------+
| 2008-12-25 23:30:00+08 |
+------------------------+
```